# How to compose a single phrase/write a sentence for this?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, sentence, sentence-meaning, construction

This is related to covid19 *issue*.

I'm not native so can't find words to describe it in a sentence. But here's what I want to write:

Since covid19 *issue* hasn't stopped yet, and we can't stop our routine works, so it's time to continue our routine tasks *(many countries are removing lockdown like in India because otherwise it would affect economy)* but we must follow the rules and take precautions. Along with that, we can do our job, household stuff etc.

Now, it doesn't mean I need to include all things in a single sentence.

Here's the sentence I've written, but I'm not sure if it's grammatically and practically correct to share online:

**Let's continue are routine tasks but with following rules and regulations and taking precautions, during this COVID19 issue.**

EDIT:

I'm also doubtful about the beginning of this sentence. **Let's continue** thing.

**Does it mean I'm saying** "You were not following this before and not doing your routine tasks before, and I'm kind of encouraging everyone to start it NOW"?

If yes, how can I improve the beginning especially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the word "are" should be "our." Otherwise, the sentence may be improved as follows:

> Let's continue our routine tasks, following rules and regulations, taking precautions during this COVID19 crisis.

Comment: can COVID19 crisis be COVID19 pandemic?

Comment: Certainly, @Vikas. I just thought that "issue" was too weak a word.

Comment: I was specifically doubtful about the beginning. Can you please check edit?

Comment: I read "Let's continue" to mean that we were before doing our routine tasks to the best of our abilities under the added COVID19 restrictions, and you are encouraging us to maintain that pattern of cautious behavior as we move forward.

Comment: Oh got it. If it had been "Let's start" that could be wrong.